# Container's content is ignoring the navbar and main banner in mobile view

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

Good Day Everyone!

So I recently finished my first website, however I'm busy polishing it since there is some compatibility issues with some screen sizes. There is one thing I haven't been able to figure out or fix and that is the fact that in my teams page if you look at it in a mobile view (either through a mobile or chrome dev tools) you will notice that my container is ignoring my banner and navbar. This results in a huge space at the bottom of the page. The only solution I've thinked of is perhaps creating margin-top for the container but that would result in a lot of media queries. Is there perhaps a reason why it is ignoring it or a better solution?

Thank You!

The website: [SeveregamingZA](http://vivaz.pythonanywhere.com/)

The HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

<!-- Title of Page -->

<title> Teams - Severe Gaming </title>

<!-- Bootstrap CDN and requirements -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<!-- Custom CSS -->

<link rel="shorcut icon" type="image/png" href="/static/images/favicon.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/teams.css"/> 
<script src="/static/scripts/teams.js"></script>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title> Severe Gaming </title>
</head>

<body>

<!--Main Navigation bar-->

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
   <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
    <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/news/">News</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/teams/">Teams</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/matches/">Matches</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/media/">Media</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/sponsors/">Sponsors</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/contact/">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<!-- Main Banner -->

<div class="banner"></div>


<!-- User Controls -->


<!-- Main Body Container -->


<!-- Top Container -->

<div class="container-fluid">


<!--- DOTA 2 -->

 <section class="strips">
  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
      <h1 class="strip__title" data-name="Lorem"></h1>
      <div class="strip__inner-text">
        <div class="blackback">
        <h2>SEVERE DOTA 2</h2>

        <!--- DOTA 2 TEAM INFO -->

        <div class="row justify-content-center">

          <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="/media/PPdefault.jpg" class="contain"/>
                <h3>Lorin "Sil" Bohm</h3>
                <p>Position:  </p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="/media/PPdefault.jpg" class="contain"/>
                <h3>Michael "AcidMan" Davis</h3>
                <p>Position:  </p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="/media/PPdefault.jpg" class="contain"/>
                <h3>Ryan "Psuedo" Roux</h3>
                <p>Position:  </p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="/media/PPdefault.jpg" class="contain"/>
                <h3>Nicholas "Ench" Weyer</h3>
                <p>Position:  </p>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="/media/PPdefault.jpg" class="contain"/>
                <h3>Martin "VivAZ" Buxmann</h3>
                <p>Position:  </p>
          </div>

        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>

    <!--- CSGO -->

  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
      <h1 class="strip__title" data-name="Ipsum"></h1>
      <div class="strip__inner-text">
        <div class="blackback">
        <h2>Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</h2>

        <!--- CSGO TEAM INFO -->

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="lookingforteam"> We are currently looking for a Counter-Strike team to play for us! If interested use the contact form located on the website to contact us!</div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>

    <!--- Hearthstone -->

  <article class="strips__strip">
    <div class="strip__content">
      <h1 class="strip__title" data-name="Ipsum"></h1>
      <div class="strip__inner-text">
        <div class="blackback">
        <h2>Hearthstone</h2>

        <!--- Hearthstone TEAM INFO -->

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="lookingforteam"> We are currently looking for Hearthstone players to play for us! If interested use the contact form located on the website to contact us!</div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>

    <!--- LoL -->

    <article class="strips__strip">
      <div class="strip__content">
        <h1 class="strip__title" data-name="Ipsum"></h1>
        <div class="strip__inner-text">
          <div class="blackback">
          <h2>League of Legends</h2>

          <!--- LoL TEAM INFO -->

          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="lookingforteam"> We are currently looking for a League Of Legends team to play for us! If interested use the contact form located on the website to contact us!</div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <!--- Rocket League -->

    <article class="strips__strip">
      <div class="strip__content">
        <h1 class="strip__title" data-name="Ipsum"></h1>
        <div class="strip__inner-text">
          <div class="blackback">
          <h2>Rocket League</h2>

          <!--- Rocket League TEAM INFO -->

          <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="lookingforteam"> We are currently looking for a Rocket League team to play for us! If interested use the contact form located on the website to contact us!</div>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>




    <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-left strip__close"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right strip__close"></i>
  </section>

  </div>     


<!-- Footer -->

<div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

There are two CSS files. One is based on the base template which is the style.css which gets rendered in every page and then there is the unique css which is teams.css:

style.css

```
/* Main HTML */

* {
  margin: 0;
  color: white;

}

html {
  font-family: Roboto, elvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #0b0e17;
}

/* Navigation Bar*/

a {
  color: #ffffff;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 0.3;
  background: url("/static/images/menu-glass.png");
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbar{
  top: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:21;
  position: fixed;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: url("/static/images/nav-bar.png");
  background-position: center;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 23px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

.navbar-collapse{
  margin-top:10px;
  background-color: rgba(11,14,23, 0.7);
}

.nav-item {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.nav-item:hover{
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgb(11,14,23);
}

/* Collapsed Hamburger Custom Settings */

.navbar-toggler {
    width: 50px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border:none;
}
.navbar-toggler .line{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #000;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}


/* Banner */

.banner {
  margin-top: 90px;
  background: url("/static/images/banner.png");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 392px;
}

/* Control Center */
.buttons{
  padding-top: 20px; 

}

.btn-link{
  background: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color:white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.highlight{
  font-size: 1rem;
}


div.user-controls-container{
  width:100%;
  height:70px;
  text-align: right;
}

.inline{
  display:inline;
  margin-right: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Footer */

.footer {
  bottom:0;
  background: url("/static/images/footer.png");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

teams.css

```
.container-fluid{
    padding:0 !important;
}

.strips {
  height: 90vh;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: white;
}
.strips__strip {
  will-change: width, left, z-index, height;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20%;
  height: 90vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.strips__strip:nth-child(1) {
  left: 0%;
}
.strips__strip:nth-child(2) {
  left: 20%;
}
.strips__strip:nth-child(3) {
  left: 40%;
}
.strips__strip:nth-child(4) {
  left: 60%;
}
.strips__strip:nth-child(5) {
  left: 80%;
}
.strips__strip:nth-child(1) .strip__content {
  background-image: url("/static/images/dota2-teams.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  animation-name: strip1;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
.strips__strip:nth-child(2) .strip__content {
  background-image: url("/static/images/csgo-teams.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  animation-name: strip2;
  animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
.strips__strip:nth-child(3) .strip__content {
  background-image: url("/static/images/hearthstone-teams.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  animation-name: strip3;
  animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
.strips__strip:nth-child(4) .strip__content {
  background-image: url("/static/images/lol-teams.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  animation-name: strip4;
  animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
.strips__strip:nth-child(5) .strip__content {
  background-image: url("/static/images/rocket-teams.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  animation-name: strip5;
  animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {



  .strips__strip {
    max-height: 20vh;
  }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(2) {
    top: 20vh;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(3) {
    top: 40vh;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(4) {
    top: 60vh;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .strips__strip:nth-child(5) {
    top: 80vh;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
.strips .strip__content {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.strips .strip__content:hover:before {
  transform: skew(-30deg) scale(3) translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 0.1;
}
.strips .strip__content:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.05;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: skew(-30deg) scaleY(1) translate(0, 0);
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.strips .strip__inner-text {
  will-change: transform, opacity;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.5);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
.strips__strip--expanded {
  width: 100%;

  left: 0 !important;
  z-index: 3;
  cursor: default;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .strips__strip--expanded {
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
}
.strips__strip--expanded .strip__content:hover:before {
  transform: skew(-30deg) scale(1) translate(0, 0);
  opacity: 0.05;
}
.strips__strip--expanded .strip__title {
  opacity: 0;
}
.strips__strip--expanded .strip__inner-text {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
.strip__title {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  color: white;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  .strip__title {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}
.strip__close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 3vw;
  top: 3vw;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.strip__close--show {
  opacity: 1;
}
@keyframes strip1 {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes strip2 {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes strip3 {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes strip4 {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes strip5 {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }
}
/* Demo purposes */

.fas {
  position: sticky;
  right: 90vw;
  top:40vh;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
}

.fa{
  position: sticky;
  left: 90vw;
  top: 40vh;
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
}

h2{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

h3{
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: bold;
}
p {
  margin: 0 0 16px;
}

.footer{
    display:none;
}

.blackback{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    padding: 30px 0 0 0;
}

.box {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.teams-container{
  display:flex;
}

.teams-container div{
  padding: 10px;
}

.playerprofile{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}

.profilepic {
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/4jmxcF9/Red.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: auto;
  height: 140px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


.contain {
  object-fit: cover ;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.lookingforteam{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  padding-bottom:30px;
}
```

Javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var Expand = (function() {
        var tile = $('.strips__strip');
        var tileLink = $('.strips__strip > .strip__content');
        var tileText = tileLink.find('.strip__inner-text');
        var stripClose = $('.strip__close');

        var expanded  = false;

        var open = function() {

          var tile = $(this).parent();

            if (!expanded) {
              tile.addClass('strips__strip--expanded');
              // add delay to inner text
              tileText.css('transition', 'all .5s .3s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)');
              stripClose.addClass('strip__close--show');
              stripClose.css('transition', 'all .6s 1s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)');
              expanded = true;
            } 
          };

        var close = function() {
          if (expanded) {
            tile.removeClass('strips__strip--expanded');
            // remove delay from inner text
            tileText.css('transition', 'all 0.15s 0 cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)');
            stripClose.removeClass('strip__close--show');
            stripClose.css('transition', 'all 0.2s 0s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1)')
            expanded = false;
          }
        }

          var bindActions = function() {
            tileLink.on('click', open);
            stripClose.on('click', close);
          };

          var init = function() {
            bindActions();
          };

          return {
            init: init
          };

        }());

      Expand.init();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was pretty simple I had to change to position of the container-fluid to relative! This fixed the problem!